# initialize keyboard event without clicking the stage

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-cs5, keyboard-events

i am using this code to play my animation using my keyboard, but for some reason i dont understand, i need to click on the stage first to make it work whe it should work automaticaly, can anyone help me to fix this please?

> var collage
>
> collage=0
>
> function gocollage1(e:KeyboardEvent):void
>
> {
>
> if (collage==0 && e.keyCode == Keyboard.RIGHT)
>
> {
>
> collage=1
>
> myanimation.play();
>
> }
>
> }
>
> stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, gocollage1);

Comment: The stage needs focus before it can capture key events for security reasons. You could create a reason for clicking the stage, a 'start' or 'accept to continue' for example.

Comment: Do you mean stage or swf?

Comment: the stage needs focus, they've attached the eventlistener to the stage. They could essentially be the same thing, stage and swf..what do you mean? Someone needs to click the swf(stage) yes

Comment: i have to click anywhere in the stage to be able to use my keyboard

Comment: The stage and the swf is not the same thing. Setting the focus to stage is not a big deal. Setting the focus to the swf is.

Comment: I agree but in this instance the swf/stage needs focus for key events no?  I thought without clicking the swf initially the stage wont get focus to accept key events?

Comment: @ Fygo my goal is not to have to use the mouse to start other animations

Comment: sorry Fygo, was completely wrong of me to blur the distinction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to set the swf focus to the stage.

```
stage.focus = stage;
```